# Mongoose Model inheritance: How to put an extended model in its own file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to use inheritance with Mongoose in an Express app and my starting point is [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/1647) where they discuss how the feature is implemented.

My model is simple: an abstract BookableAbstractSchema schema, and a MeetingRoom schema that extends Bookable.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var util = require('util');

// Define our user schema
var BookableAbstractSchema = function (){
    Schema.apply(this,arguments);
    this.add({
        spaceId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Space'},
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    });
}
util.inherits(BookableAbstractSchema, Schema);

var BookableSchema = new BookableAbstractSchema();
var bookable = mongoose.model('bookable', BookableSchema);


// MEETING ROOM
var MeetingRoomSchema = new BookableAbstractSchema({
    something:String
});

var meetingRoom = bookable.discriminator('MeetingRoom', MeetingRoomSchema);
module.exports.MeetingRoom = meetingRoom;
```

Until then it works great.

I am having dificulty when I want to put each Schema in its own file

bookable.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var util = require('util');

// Define our user schema
var BookableAbstractSchema = function (){
    Schema.apply(this,arguments);
    this.add({
        spaceId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Space'},
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    });
}
util.inherits(BookableAbstractSchema, Schema);

var BookableSchema = new BookableAbstractSchema();
module.exports= mongoose.model('bookable', BookableSchema);
```

meetingroom.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Bookable = require('./bookable');

var MeetingRoomSchema = new Bookable({
    something:String
});

module.exports = Bookable.discriminator('MeetingRoom', MeetingRoomSchema); // error described below is thrown here.
```

But then I get the following error in the console:

```
throw new Error("You must pass a valid discriminator Schema");
```

When I debug, 'MeetingRoom' is indeed an instance of `model`, not `schema`

This is where I am getting lost and I need help :) Why does this work when it's all in the same file and not when the models are separated in different files?

Answer (score 2):

The `MeetingRoomSchema` actually needs to be of the type `mongoose.Schema`, not a new `Bookable` Object.

Here's the relevant validation in mongoose's source code:

```
  if (!(schema instanceof Schema)) {
    throw new Error("You must pass a valid discriminator Schema");
  }
```

The above is referenced from these [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator)

Therefore, `MeetingRoomSchema` should be defined as below:

```
var MeetingRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  something: String
});

module.exports = Bookable.discriminator('MeetingRoom', MeetingRoomSchema);
```

Hope this helps!